# Merge two fields into a new object field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using this code :

```
db.collection.updateMany({},[{ $set: {points: [ "$latitude", "$longitude" ] } },
                                       { $unset: [ "longitude", "latitude" ] }])
```

to create the points field based on `Latitude/Longitude` values, but i need to have a "label" on each of them so when i search then it shows something like below :

```
"points": 
 {
     [
       { 
         "latitude": -3.724404,
         "longitude": -38.557694
       }
     ]
 }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correct your documents look like this :

```
[
  {
    "_id" : 123,
    "latitude": -3.724404,
    "longitude": -38.557694
  },
  {
    "_id" : 456,
    "latitude": -3.724404,
    "longitude": -38.557694
  }
]
```

You can use this query :

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, [
  {
    $set: {
      points: [
        {
          latitude: "$latitude",
          longitude: "$longitude"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $unset: ["longitude", "latitude"] }
]);
```

To get something like this :

```
[
  {
    "_id": 123,
    "points": [
      {
        "latitude": -3.724404,
        "longitude": -38.557694
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 456,
    "points": [
      {
        "latitude": -3.724404,
        "longitude": -38.557694
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But why do you need `points` as an array, instead it can be an object like this :

```
"points": {
      "latitude": -3.724404,
      "longitude": -38.557694
    }
```

Get it with almost the same query :

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, [
  {
    $set: {
      points: 
        {
          latitude: "$latitude",
          longitude: "$longitude"
        }
    }
  },
  { $unset: ["longitude", "latitude"] }
]);
```